# Error "no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH" during GCC configuration of the build environment

Tags: gcc, path, blender

Well, I've searched other questions similar to this but in my case the problem does not seem to resolve with any of the answers.

I am installing blender 2.80 in CentOS 7, but in between I find a problem with the gcc. It says it has a problem building with gcc 4.4, which is weird because I have gcc 4.8.something but ok...

I am trying to install another version of gcc, and when I execute this code, it says that there is no acceptable compiler on the $PATH:

```
./configure --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++
```

Here is the output of that code:

```
...
checking for libcilkrts support... yes
checking for libitm support... yes
checking for libsanitizer support... yes
checking for libvtv support... yes
checking for libmpx support... yes
checking for libhsail-rt support... yes
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: in `/home/user/Documentos/Otros/blender-git/gcc-7.3.0':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
```

I tried to use:

```
gcc --version
bash: gcc: no se encontró la orden...
```

"no se encontró la orden" = "command not found" in Spanish

Also:

```
which gcc
/usr/bin/which: no gcc in (/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin)
```

```
whereis gcc
gcc: /usr/bin/gcc /usr/lib/gcc /usr/libexec/gcc /usr/share/man/man1/gcc.1.gz
```

I've tried (I'm writing this pieces of code with yum manually and not copy-pasting them so maybe I write them wrong but I executed them correctly when I tried them):

```
yum install gcc
```

```
yum install 'Development Tools"
```

But it hasn't worked. I guess my path is not correctly set but I don't know how to set it correctly and I am not an expert in Linux, installing things via shell is still a bit weird to me.

Here I make echo $PATH and it shows me the result:

```
echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/home/user/.local/bin:/home/user/bin
```

To install gcc, I'm following these steps:
https://linuxhostsupport.com/blog/how-to-install-gcc-on-centos-7/

---

-------------------------------------------------- UPDATE --------------------------------------------------

I am not answering my question, but this may be useful for other people:

After some research, I started using the code posted in the answer to this question: 
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/120890/blender-2-8-cannot-find-libmvec-so-1

I recommend to do so. Also, I advice you. CentOS 7 does not support the last Glibc version, only the 2.17, and Blender 2.80 needs the 2.24 version of Glibc I think. So the only way of using it is building yourself Blender (or something like that, I'm new in this). Anyway, maybe you appreciate this info, as maybe it's better to change the distribution or wait. Meanwhile, you can use Blender 2.79b. I hope to help someone lost in the Blender installation or other errors.

I leave you this link, in which I think they are trying to build Blender 2.8 in CentOS 7:
https://devtalk.blender.org/t/unable-to-run-blender-2-80-in-rhel-centos-7/2138/5